# Chrome does not load profile

Tags: python, selenium, automation

For some reason the program does not load the profile. The location of the profile is fine.

```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Aron\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 2")
  capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
  chromedriver = 'C:\\test\\chromedriver.exe'
  # Opening the browser
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriver, chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: How are you telling it doesn't load the profile? where is the request to get a URL, e.g. `driver.get("https://www.google.com")`

Comment: driver.get(sites['site'][0])
I have a dictionary with sites, because I have to open multiple websites. But this will not have the profile loaded, so I have to accept cookies and log in every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

1 - When using an empty folder for the profile Chrome creates a new profile in that folder. If it creates the profile you can suppose that it also loads it next time.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\test\Profile 2")

chromedriver = r'C:\test\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=options)
```

[image: The created folder]

2 - But to be sure you can show the used profile in Chrome it self with chrome://version/.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\test\Profile 2")

chromedriver = r'C:\test\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=options)

driver.get('chrome://version/')

input('Enter')
```

[image: The actual profile]

Comment: This now also works with your prillinger site. Nice way to handle the cookies, didn't know it. One thing I encountered while testing: Chrome didn't close properly and needed to restore the next run. Adding time.sleep(2), maybe less?, after driver.close() seems to solve this problem.

Comment: It says that the profile is loaded, but the cookies aren't loaded.

Comment: Did you look in 'url' chrome://settings/siteData after running the second time? Or with notepad++ in the file C:\test\Profile 2\Default\Cookies after closing the program? I have a lot of prillinger cookies in this file.